# uwsgi starts and works from console but doesn't want to with config file

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I've got an issue with uwsgi. When I start uwsgi from conole:

```
 uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:5555  --chdir /var/www/proj/smth/ --wsgi-file /var/www/.../rest_api/wsgi.py &
```

it shows web pages and everithing looks fine. But when I use uwsgi config file with something like this:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /var/www/proj
socket = :5555
wsgi-file = /var/www/proj/rest/rest_api/wsgi.py 
home = /var/www/proj
processes = 4
threads = 2
touch-reload=/var/www/proj/rest/rest_api/wsgi.py
daemonize=/var/log/uwsgi/rest.log
vacuum=true
; wtf we get errors w-out this and it won't start: 
no-site=true
```

I get an internal server error displayed in my web browser. I run nginx.

And some of my uwsgi log lines look like this:

```
ImportError: No module named ...
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
```

Answer (score 0):

the setting

```
chdir = /var/www/proj
```

doesn't look the same when you run it in command line

```
--chdir /var/www/proj/smth/
```

Is that right or just because you edited what you pasted?

Comment: Yes, I edited it. I found the solution, Thank you, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I deleted some lines in uwsgi.ini and left only these:

```
chdir = /var/www/proj/rest/
socket = 127.0.0.1:xxxx
wsgi-file = /var/www/proj/rest/rest_api/wsgi.py 
daemonize=/var/log/uwsgi/rest.log
```

Now it works.